# Out of memory: Kill process or sacrifice child on thread in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, process, out-of-memory

I have a program that check continuously a webpage content until it changes... To do this I open new threads each 0.5s, each thread has a new connection with a new proxy so the refresh seems to be very faster with more thread. I put the script on a server but after some times it stops with this string

> Out of memory: Kill process 2066 (python3) score 376 or sacrifice
>   child

how can I prevent this? Is this caused by an exceed of information in RAM memory?

**edit: to make it works better I would like to open 10 session per link. When one session will close another one replace the last closed. To do this I read about queue in thread but I don't know how to do it.**

this is how I open new threads:

```
sites = read_from_txt("links.txt")
proxy_list = read_from_txt("proxies.txt")


 # Start monitoring sites
    while(True):
        threads = []
        for link in sites:
            # skip over blank lines 
            if not link.strip():
                pass
            else :

                #threading setup
                t = Thread(target=monitor, args=(link, proxy_list))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
                time.sleep(0.5)
```